# Stress test service endpoint, send 100K requests using x threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I want to stress test my service endpoint, making http POST requests.

I want the solution to be able to either:

1. Make a certain number of requests, like 100K
2. Keep running for x number of minutes

So far I created my solution using an executorservice like:

```
int MAX_THREADS = 20;
int MAX_REQUESTS = 1000;

ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREADS);

for(int x = 0; x < MAX_REQUESTS; x++) {
  es.execute(new MyTask());
}

es.shutdown();

try {
  es.awaitTermination(..);
}
catch(...) {

}
```

Where MyTask implemented Runnable, and it makes the HttpPost using HttpClient (apache).

So this creates a set pool of threads, and then calls the task x number of times.

**How can I modify this to also be able to run for a specified number of minutes?**

For me to get start/end time statistics, I'm going to have to use futures so each thread and return back how long it took to run correct?

Also, in my runnable task, I am creating a new instance of the HttpClient object, and loading a file that I send with the post.  I'm guessing this is going to slow down my benchmark, is there a way to re-use the httpclient with everything setup except for the actual call to make the request?

Before anyone mentions it, I know there are tools like jmeter etc. that does this already, but I want to both learn how this works and I will be doing some custom things later on that I want full control over.

Comment: @VivienBarousse he mentioned he dont need JMeter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why make your own if you can use Apache JMeter? You can make a simple plugin to suit your applications needs and then have all the load generating possibilities of JMeter at your fingertips. Including running with intervals and such.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is await termination for a certain about of time and then call `es.shutdownNow()`.  So something like:

```
// start your executor service like you do
// submit your jobs
// shutdown the service so no new jobs are added
es.shutdown();
try {
   // wait for it to complete for only a certain amount of time
   if (!es.awaitTermination(1. TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
       // if timed out waiting then flush remaining jobs and interrupt running
       es.shutdownNow();
       // now wait forever for it to finish after you've stopped the jobs
       es.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   }
} catch(...) {
```

The one question I have with this is if it is legal to call `shutdownNow()` _after you've called `shutdown()`.  I'm not 100% sure about that.

**NOTE:** Your tasks, if they are long running, should watch for `InterruptedException` and should be testing for `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` if they are looping so they can be interrupted by `shutdownNow()` appropriately.

Comment: Confused, how will this let me run things for say 1 hour?

Comment: Oh, are you saying I don't use the executor service and run thigns in a while loop? still confused sorry....

Comment: All you need to do is change the `TimeUnit.MINUTES` to `TimeUnit.HOURS`.  So if your jobs have not finished in an hour, then `shutdownNow()` will be called.

Comment: No, you are still using the `ExecutorService`.  I've edited my answer to make that more plain.

Comment: hmm..but for this to work, I have to make sure the # of requests will keep running to at least the time I want it to run.  Example, if each requests takes 1 ms to finish, and I send 100 reqeusts, but want it to run for 1 hour, that won't work?

Comment: If you have 100 jobs that each take 1ms then `awaitTermination()` will return true and your `ExecutorService` will be done.  It will finish early, right?  If you want it to run for an hour then you would have to submit more of them.  Or am I not understanding what you are trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to run a particular job for an hour and then have it stop or are you running a whole bunch of small jobs and you want to stop them if they don't finish in an hour?  My code does the latter.

Comment: I want to do both, 1) run x number of requests or 2) run for 1 hour.  I want to write it in a way where I can do both types of tests (running for a certain # of requests OR running for a certain amount of time). BTW my jobs are http post reqeusts to a url.

Comment: My code will do that then.  If you submit 100 jobs that will finish in a second then the 1st `awaitTermination` will true true and you are done.  If the jobs have _not_ finished in an hour then it will remove the remaining jobs, interrupt the running ones, and then wait for them to cleanup.